# ASP.NET Core : how to restrict applying custom attribute on condition during compile time?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, custom-attributes

Here is the sample code:

```
public sealed class CustomAttribute1 : Attribute
{}

public sealed class CustomAttribute2 : Attribute
{}

[CustomAttribute1]
[CustomAttribute2]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(Userodel userModel) //assume it as an action inside a mvc controller
{ }
```

As per the business need, `UpdateAsync()` can be either decorated with `[CustomAttribute1]` or `[CustomAttribute2]`, or without none of them, but NOT with both of them for the SAME action method.

How to restrict the developer (at compile time) from decorating an action method with both `[CustomAttribute1]` and `[CustomAttribute2]` ?

Comment: You could do this with a custom analyzer to catch it at compile time, but that can be a bit complex. I've solved similar things with unit tests in the past though. It is fairly easy to do with reflection though it won't be caught if people don't run tests locally (but the CI environment would catch it).

Comment: This sounds somewhat like an XY problem to me. What exactly is the problem is having them both? Could you re-engineer the project so the issue goes away?

Comment: At compile time?  No easy way I can think of comes to mind.  The best ways to handle compile time (minus messing with the actual compiler) would be to add a check during MSBUILD, use static code analysis, or write unit tests so the build fails.  Runtime I can think of a myriad of ways but that's not what you're looking for.  Personally I'd fix the design.

Comment: @DavidG, Problem in using both the attributes is redundancy. Because both attributes doing same thing to an extent so having either one of those attributes is enough for all the current use cases, having said that still developers can able to add both of them at present, which is something I don't want. P.S: one of attributes is used in production & another is introduced recently.

Comment: Have you considered adding a parameter to the attribute in production to enhance its behaviour instead of adding a new attribute?

Comment: @Clemens, like you suggested introducing parameter in the existing attribute to exhibit new behavior is relatively better approach then introducing altogether brand new attribute. Thanks. Technically, though developers still call attribute() and also attribute(param) on same controller, but by common sense it can be avoided

Answer (score 0):

In project properties, in Compilation, there are a TextBox "Conditionally compilation symbols". Define, for example MODE1. Then, in your code:

```
#if MODE1
[CustomAttribute1]
#elif MODE2
[CustomAttribute1]
#endif
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(...)
```

Now, you can need create some configurations, like the DEBUG and RELEASE created by default. Create, for example, DEBUG1 and DEBUG2 and set MODE1 to DEBUG1 and MODE2 to DEBUG2.

If you debug with DEBUG1 configuration, you'll use CustomAttribute1. With DEBUG2, CustomAttribute2. And with DEBUG, none of them.

**UPDATE**

Sorry, I missunderstood your question. May be an option move the solution to the attribute implementation?

```
[AttributeUsage(AllowMultiple = false)]
public sealed class CustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    private bool _useMode1;

    public CustomAttribute(bool useMode1)
    {
        _useMode1 = useMode1;
    }

    // Do things in a way or other depending of _useMode1
}
```

With previous approach, you have only one attribute and use the parameter to select between your current 1 and 2 attributes. Also, you can't add more than once (because `AttributeUsage` -> `AllowMultiple`):

```
[CustomAttribute(true)]
public async Task<IActionResult> UpdateAsync(...)
```

Comment: OP is asking how to prevent them both from being added not how either can be added.

Comment: @DavidG I'm spanish and sometimes I missunderstood things but in the question I can read "or without none of them". So I understand that is asking for a simple way to choose  between CustomAttribute1, CustomAttribute2 or none. And I thing that change the configuration in the dropdown to use one of these is a simple way to do that.

Comment: OK, in that case you read the question wrong I'm afraid. They want the code shown above to not compile because both attributes have been added at the same time.